# Find start and end point for every series consecutive number matlab

Tags: matlab

Let say, I have `A=[1 1 1 4 4 4 4 4 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 3 3 3 3 3]`. The series number is `B=[1:24]`
My question is how can I find the start and end for every consecutive number. 
Should be start and end point of my answer is

```
for A=1 is 1,3;9,10;13,14;17,19
for A=2 is 11,12;15,16
for A=3 is 20,24
for A=4 is 4,8`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
n = 1;
B = find(diff([0,A==n,0]));         %//Find where sequences of n and not  begin
B(2:2:end) = B(2:2:end) - 1       %//Change from the beginning of not n sequence to the end of the n sequence
reshape(B, 2, [])'
```

OR now that you want 2 columns it's easier (and more logical) to do this:

```
s = find(diff([0,A==n,0])==1);
e = find(diff([0,A==n,0])==-1) -1;
B = [s', e']
```

Comment: Yes. Tq very much. I get it

Comment: @danjoro if might have some issues though, you'll need to test thoroughly and tweak. e.g. if you have a single `1` at the end, is it still doing what you want?

Comment: Yes, this that is one prob. How can I solve it. And how can I range the result like this B=[1 3; 9,10; 13,14; 17,19];. Another one problem is A=3 only read starting point 20 but end point 24 cannot read.

Comment: Get it!! tq very much